# How To Change A Sprite Image When Tapped

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I know this is probably one of the easiest questions ever to answer, but I've done some searching and can't seem to find the answer to this... How do I change a sprites image when the user taps on it in Cocos2d-x?

The only way I know of is using a menu image like this:

`auto box = MenuItemImage::create("box_untapped.png", "box_tapped.png");`

but that only changes the image while the user is tapping it.. how do I get it to stay changed even after they let go of the button?

Comment: change the spriteFrame or texture property

Comment: @LearnCocos2D would I not use a MenuItemImage then? I guess I'm not understanding your idea..

Comment: you said sprite image, so I thought you were not using Menu Items but making your own touchable sprite. In any case you can access the children of the menu, but if the menu is anything like in cocos2d-iphone it's really resistant to any outside changes (they are ignored/overridden or lead to issues with touch detection). However there may be a toggle flag or toggle menu item as there is in cocos2d-iphone. Check the class/API reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code do not need any menu/button/... but a `Touch Listener` :

```
auto mySprite = Sprite("A.png");

auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    ///
touchListener->onTouchBegan = [=](Touch* touch, Event* event){
    auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
    Point locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());
    Size s = target->getContentSize();
    Rect rect = Rect(0, 0, s.width, s.height);
    if (rect.containsPoint(locationInNode))
    {
        mySprite->setTexture("B.png"); // Here
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

touchListener->onTouchEnded(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    mySprite->setTexture("B.png"); // Or Here
}
_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, mySprite);
```

Hope helps